# Is it possible to print a char in between Multi-Dimensional Array in Java?

Tags: java

I am still learning to code in Java and I want to build Multi-Dimensional arrays where I want it to print two numbers and a char in between so I can randomize maths multipication questions for my  son to exercise.

So far I have managed to get it done but 'x' is also printing at the end. All I want to print is randoming two numbers and printing as ( 1 x 2 = ).

This is what I have so far :

```
package exercises;

public class TimeTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] nums = new int[10][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                nums[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(nums[i][j] + " x ");
            }
            System.out.println("=");
        }
    }

}
```

and it prints the following when I run it:

```
7 x 1 x =
9 x 9 x =
6 x 3 x =
0 x 6 x =
0 x 2 x =
0 x 4 x =
0 x 8 x =
8 x 5 x =
8 x 8 x =
8 x 3 x =
```

I do not want the last 'x' before the equal sign.

Thank you all.

I tried to print the equal sign only and it was confusing. I tried to print first line of the array and then another seperate function to print the last bit of the array with '+' and it didnt worked instead it throw and huge error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      
            System.out.println(nums[i][0] + " x "+nums[i][1]+" = ");
        
    }
```

Comment: I still do not understand how this works but it works... How can you print two lines without needing to have nested loops? This is very interesting. I will need to learn this...

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) { } here, loop works for j=0 and 1  for  i = 0,1,2,3...9  that mean   we can use nums[i][0] and nums[i][1] for each value of i

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I did a separate java code and tried your solution for a single Array and it also worked. I now understand how it works and how to use it. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(nums[i][j]);
                if(j == 0)
                  System.out.print(" x ");
            }
            System.out.println("=");
}
```